# How to get output of shell in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, shell

In linux I can use ! to start a shell command:

```
mysql >\! ping localhost
```

Is there a way to get the output of shell in MySQL?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the output of the shell?

Answer (score 0):

While in the mysql prompt, no. You can however pipe the results of a command into mysql with something similar to:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword < `ping localhost`
```

The only issue with this is that whatever your shell command returns needs to be the sum of the commands/data you want to issue to mysql. This is most commonly used to execute a script or something similar.

Comment: No,this is not run in MySQL environment.